# Is it possible to automate the export of videos from Unreal Engine so that assets are swapped out dynamically?

Tags: unreal-4, video, export

Let's say I have an unreal project that features a character in an environment. I want to use Unreal to cycle through characters and environments and create a number of videos. Let's say for instance I have 4 characters and 4 environments, this would equate to 16 distinct videos. Is there any mechanism for automating such a process using Unreal Engine?